# At or in my home

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about the preposition usage with *home*.

Saying:

> I have a same style furnishing **in** (or **at**) my home

In this case, *in* seems to me too specific to describe its placement, but I am not sure if *at* can be used with *home*

Comment: It would probably be better to use *house* (the physical structure that you live in) instead of *home*, especially since the item mentioned is a fixed object.

Answer (score 1):

When I started this answer I was 100% certain I knew the answer:

I would say (Brit)

> "I have this exact vase in my house"

but then I thought about it more, and realised I would also say

"I have a soda stream at home".

so what is the difference when would I use one and not the other

I wouldn't say "I have this exact vase at my house"

But "Don't worry I have one at home" is good as is 
"Of course I have a sofa at home" or "or course I have a sofa at my house"

This isn't a complete answer, but it seems okay to use both is where I think I ended up.

Comment: You could conclude by explaining how "at home" can often be used to mean "in my house." For example: _Where were you on the night of the twelfth?_ "I was at home" (or, "I was in my house").