# 'in the summer house' of 'at the summer house'?

Tags: prepositions

If you want to describe the fact that some family went out side the city to their summer house, would you use "at" or "in"

> "Where are they now?"
>
> "Well, it's a vacation now, so I suppose they are **at/in the summer
>   house**."

Comment: in the summer house = physically inside the summer house; at the summer house = in close proximity to the summer house, which might also include inside.

Comment: But," they are staying at the summer house" implies their current accommodations and they may be inside or outside the building, or neither if they have gone to the beach.

Comment: My personal opinion is you would use "they are staying in the summer house" only in situations where you wanted to indicate that there was a choice of alternatives.

Comment: @BruceMurray - "...only in situations where you wanted to indicate that there was a choice of alternatives" - Can you, please, elaborate. What choice of alternatives do you mean? Is going to the beach not a choice of alternatives? If yes, then you seem to contradict your last comment, in which you said that it's okay to say "they are at the summer house" when they are actually at the beach.

Comment: It okay to say they are "staying" at the summer house, when they are at the beach because it refers to their location.  Without "staying"  it does not work

Comment: Assuming you mean what the British would call a 'holiday cottage' (a second home), I would use _at_. What we call a summer house is a shelter built in a large garden to sit _in_  in hot weather. https://www.wickes.co.uk/Products/Gardens/Garden-Buildings/Summerhouses/c/1000731

Comment: Does this answer your question? [At or in my home](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176826/at-or-in-my-home)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - Not really because that question is about the word 'home', not 'house'.

Comment: @BruceMurray - But what if I don't want to use the word "stay"? What if it's just 'are' (like in my example: 'they are at/in their summer house")?

Comment: @brilliant:  Oh, come *on!* Admittedly the linked question *primarily* focuses on "home". But there are **6** (count 'em! :) instances of the word "**house**" sprinkled among the comments and answers there, including an initial comment pointing out that *It would probably be better to use **house** (the physical structure that you live in) instead of **home***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - Yes, you are right. But those are just comments while I would want to have a canonical answer - to have this case closed for me once and for good - on when to use 'in' with 'house' and when to use 'at' with 'house'. Besides, in my case it's not just 'house', but the two-word noun 'summer house', which may also bring in some dimension that is not considered on that page at all.

Comment: Choosing between ***in*** or ***at*** in such contexts really is just a matter of using a ***container*** or a *[spatial displacement] **container*** metaphor. You should make your choice of preposition after considering *that* aspect, not by learning and remembering an almost infinitely long set of possible referent nouns.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - So, when it's a physical container, I must use 'in', and when it's a [spatial displacement] container metaphor, I should use 'at'. Right?

Comment: More precisely, when *you want to think of / present* something as being ***in*** a "physical container" or ***at*** a "location". In the case of something like a *[summer] **house***, both perspectives are perfectly natural, but in any *specific* context one or the other might be more obviously relevant *(**in** the summerhouse sheltering from the rain, **at** your friend's house all afternoon, now the lockdown rules have been eased)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - I see. Thank you. Looks like a valid answer to me that is worth of being re-written as an answer instead of just staying as a comment.

Comment: Okay, you make a good case. (The clincher being that the last sentence of the one and only answer in that "duplicate" I linked to actually starts with the words ***This isn't a complete answer*** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think it's worth noting [this NGram usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20my%20house%2Cin%20my%20house%2Cat%20my%20home%2Cin%20my%20home&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20my%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20my%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20my%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20my%20home%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

It's important to note that this chart *doesn't* imply that ***house*** is "better" than ***home***, or that you should use the preposition ***in*** rather than ***at*** in such contexts. I just put up the chart to show that all variations are commonly used.

The ***in*** or ***at*** choice here reflects using a ***container*** or a *[spatial displacement] **surface*** metaphor to identify a ***location***. It depends whether you want to think of / describe something as being ***in**[side]* a "physical container" or ***at*** a "position".

In the case of something like OP's *[summer] **house***, both perspectives are perfectly natural, but in any specific context one or the other might be more obviously relevant. You might be ***in** the summerhouse sheltering from the rain*, but on another day you might be ***at** at your friend's house all afternoon* (now the lockdown rules have been eased).

I switched from *summer house* to plain *house* for my second example above because it's *easier* to see the strength of the "location" allusions there. But it's perfectly possible to imagine contexts where "location" trumps "container" for a ***summer** house*. You've become separated from your friend at a very grand garden party (in a *very* large garden), for example, so you send him a text message saying

> ***Where are you? I'm at the summerhouse**.*

... where it might be completely irrelevant whether you're actually ***inside*** the summerhouse, or standing just outside it so you can get a better signal on your mobile phone.

Comment: ngrams is completely irrelevant here. in my home/house and at my home/house mean different things.

Comment: No - they don't "mean" different things. For all practical purposes they actually ***mean*** exactly the same thing *in those contexts OP is asking about* (i.e. - the ones where both prepositions seem "possible" to him). Where they differ is in ***nuance / allusion***, as I've explained in the answer. And the fact that not every house is a home (or a "summer house") has no real bearing on the relevant preposition usages, so why bring it up?

Comment: in and at mean different things depending on context.

Comment: You seem to be just aggressively restating what I've already written in my answer

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica This is ***such a comprehensive answer*** and *an extraordinary research that deserves to be upvoted.* You got one from me. Well done !

Answer (score 1):

- to stay at a place [hotel,motel, summer home or house]. You spend a period of time on vacation **at a place**. OR: in a town or city.

You do not stay **in your summer home**, to describe a vacation time, generically.

BUT: You have arrived in the town where your summer home/house is located. The summer house has a guest house that is separate from the main house.

Q: "Are John and Lucy staying *in* the house or the guest house?"
A: "They are staying **in the guest house** but I was surprised they were staying **at the property** at all this year. But, then,  they do like **staying in** town, you know. They don't like **staying at the lake** where they have a cottage."